# How to print all dictionary values from loop using BeautifulSoup and Flask

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup, jinja2

```
def search():
    query = "xxx"
    r = requests.get('website?q=' + query)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    results=[]
    for row in soup.findAll('li', attrs = {'class':'res'}):
        result = {}
        result['urltext'] = row.a.text
        result['url'] = row.cite.text
        results.append(result)

        return render_template('site.html', urll = result['url'], urltext = result['urltext'])
    else:
        return render_template('start.html')
```

When used like that i am getting single result in site.html, it's like the loop is stopping and getting first result and passing it to the site.html. And i want all results it finds to be passed.

```
def search():
    query = "xxx"
    r = requests.get('website?q=' + query)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    results=[]
    for row in soup.findAll('li', attrs = {'class':'res'}):
        result = {}
        result['urltext'] = row.a.text
        result['url'] = row.cite.text
        results.append(result)

        print (result['url'])
```

Using **print** gives me all results. 
But that is pointless, unless i will drop the **render_template** idea and print whole HTML with **result['url']** and **result['urltext']** in it somehow.

Comment: Clarify your question, try to print(results) to get the help?

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken, so it’s difficult to be certain of anything.

Comment: @AMC fixed. The results are either single url or all urls (when printing result['url'])

Comment: don't use `return` inside `for`-loop. `return` ends function at once so it never get next value from `findAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `return` which always ends function at once so next loop will be never executed. So don't use `return` inside `for`-loop.

And using `else` with `for` is also wrong idea because `else` will be executed only when you use `break` in `for`-loo. `for/else` doesn't work like `if/else`.

Another problem is `result['url']` and `result['urltext']` in `render_template` - it will have only last value. You have all values in `results`, not in `result['url']` and `result['urltext']`. Maybe you should send it as

```
return render_template('site.html', results=results)
```

and inside template use

```
{% for row in results %}
   <a href="{{ row.url }}">{{ row.ulrtext }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

---

```
def search():
    query = "xxx"
    r = requests.get('website?q=' + query)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    results = []
    for row in soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class': 'res'}):
        result = {}
        result['urltext'] = row.a.text
        result['url'] = row.cite.text
        results.append(result)

    if results:
        return render_template('site.html', results=results)
    else:
        return render_template('start.html')
```